# Formatting data to use Confluent JDBC Sink Connector via ksql

Tags: jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, ksqldb

I'd like to use the Confluent JDBC Sink Connector via ksql to write to ClickHouse database.
I have a c# application that writes the data to Kafka topic. How can I format the message from my application, so that it is acceptable for sink to write to the database? I don't want to use the Schema Registry or other ksql constructs.

Answer (score 0):

KSQL accepts JSON or CSV data, however ClickHouse has it's own Kafka Connector, so shouldn't need JDBC Sink, which will only work with a message with a schema (meaning you will need to use the Schema Registry, which is not only a KSQL construct and can be used in your C# code as well)